# JSON guarantee order or parameters for XML API that requires it

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have an API that is validating against an XML schema whose order is set to sequence. This means the order of the parameters has to be in a specific order. My javascript sends request to the server JSON in either a GET or POST. I know the javascript and JSON spec say that Objects are unordered lists so the original order is not guaranteed. But is there any way to ensure the order is maintained when it's sent to the server?

Right now I'm using jQuery.extend() to merge my default parameters with user input to create the data object to send to the server. The only thing I can think of is to manually build my objects for every API call, which would be a hassle. Doing that seems fragile to me and I still can't guarantee the output will be in the correct order because it depends on how the browser sends the object.

Here is an example JSON payload for a POST request.

```
{
    "headers": {
        "sourceName": "ss",
        "transactionId": 1234,
        "timestamp": "2015-01-14T15:59:34.588Z"
    },
    "dataArea": {
        "userId": "user_id_1234",
        "accountId": "account_id_1234",
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Schmoe",
        "email": "fake@example.org"
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever had to deal an API the required parameters to be in a specific order?

Comment: No. JS objects have no specific order, and you can't force them to have one either.

Comment: Can't you use an array?

Comment: How do you validate JSON against an XML schema??

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, how would I use an array? I need key:value pairs so that I can do userId: 1234.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not doing the validation. The server converts to XML and then validates the XML to the XSD schema.

Comment: Well assuming the server obeys the ordering of object properties in the transmitted JSON, the only way I can think of to do this reliably is to write your own JSON serializer that knows how to impose some ordering in the serialized form. Once an object is serialized, of course, the ordering in that form is stable (because it's just a string).

Comment: @MichaelTurnwall I have no idea because none of us know how you're transforming the JSON to the XML or what about the process you can and can't change. You can still have, for example, an array of key-value pairs. Will that break everything? I don't know. But it would keep them in order.